# How to authenticate Tinder API using FB Access token and user id

Tags: ios, facebook, api, afnetworking-3, tinder

I have been trying to do Tinder authentication using FB access token and user id. I have successfully integrated FB SDK and got the details. And I followed the API documentation given in [link](https://github.com/fbessez/Tinder/blob/master/README.md).

But when I call Tinder auth API, I am getting 'unauthorized 401' error. Don't know what I am missing here, please find below the code which I used.

```
   AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Tinder/4.7.1 (iPhone; iOS 9.2; Scale/2.00)" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-agent"];

    NSString *userId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_LOGGED_IN_USERID_KEY];
    NSDictionary *parameterDic = @{@"facebook_token": accessToken, @"facebook_id": userId};

    [manager POST:TINDER_AUTH_URL parameters:parameterDic progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success! %@", responseObject);    
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the `X-Auth-Token` header to the Facebook token `accessToken`, which may cause the 401 error. You should only set it in the following requests to the Tinder token you will get in the response of the auth request.

Comment: I tried without that as well, and was getting the same error. And as per the API doc, it should be added.

Comment: Actually, the API document you linked states: "All curls must be sent with the headers as well (the only exception is that the /auth call must not have the X-Auth-Token header)". What are you using as userId and TINDER_AUTH_URL ?

Comment: User id is FB logged user's user id and TINDER_AUTH_URL is https://api.gotinder.com/auth

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! That finally led me to solving the issue. The x-auth-token must be set to the Tinder token that you get in the response from the auth call (which uses the FB token)!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I've created a repo on Github. You'll get idea how it works. More info: https://tinder.bhavukjain.com

/***************/

You're using the wrong tags:

Setup the params something like this:

```
let params:[String:Any] = ["locale":"en-IN",
                           "force_refresh": false,
                           "facebook_token":token,
                           "facebook_id":fbId]
```

Comment: I looked into the code, but at the end the auth process is same. And the url used is https://api.gotinder.com/user/auth and I was trying without '/user'. But could you simply tell the how the auth process is done? I implemented the same auth method like you did, but I am getting 401. Is there any dependency for authentication? The authentication won't work on simulator?

Comment: I've already explained you through above code, and the same thing is implemented in the repo. But since you're not able to make it work, I shared the whole baked code. Now you have to check what you're missing. The facebook login will not work on simulator, but the tinder api /auth will work on the simulator.